# toggle div tags background colors on radio button click with Jquery/css

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have two html radio button in each of two div tags with values 1 and 2.  radio button 1 is the default selected and the containing div background-color is lime.  The div tag containing radio button 2 background color is orange.  The div tags are positioned as desired with the css below.  When I click on radio button 2 I want its containing div background-color to change to lime and the div containing radio button 1 background color to change to orange.  Here is what I have attempted -- the Jquery function is pseudo code for now.  What is the correct Jquery to be able to toggle the background colors of the div tags?  Do I need to change the css?  Maybe make both divs the same css class?

```
<style type="text/css">
    ....
    .cdiv1 {
        width:130px;
        float:left;
    }
    .cdiv2 {
        width:155px;
        float:left;
    }

</style>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        if($(this).find('input[type="radio"]').is(':checked').value == 1){
            $( ".cdiv1 ).css( "background-color", "green" );
        }
        else{
            $( ".cdiv2 ).css( "background-color", "green" );
    }
    });
</script>
------------------------------------------------------
.....

<div id="divMain" class="divcontainer">
    <div id="divsrch1" class="cdiv1">
        <input type="radio" id="rb1" name="rbsearch" value="1" checked />
        <label for="searchlike" class="clblsrch1">Search like</label>
    </div>
    <div id="divsrch2" class="cdiv2">
        <input type="radio" id="rb2" name="rbsearch" value="2" />                                      
        <label for="searchonlyfor" class="clblsrch2">Search ony for</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pure CSS solution

```css
.cdiv1 {
  width: 130px;
  float: left;
}

.cdiv2 {
  width: 155px;
  float: left;
}

input[type=radio] {
  display: none;
}

input[type=radio]+label:before {
  height: 12px;
  width: 12px;
  margin-right: 2px;
  content: " ";
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #777;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

input[id=r1]+label:before,
input[id=r2]+label:before {
  background: orange;
}

input[id=r1]:checked+label:before,
input[id=r2]:checked+label:before {
  background: lime;
}
```

```html
<div id="divMain" class="divcontainer">
  <div id="divsrch1" class="cdiv1">
    <input type="radio" name="r" id="r1" checked><label for="r1" value="1">Search like</label>
  </div>
  <div id="divsrch2" class="cdiv2">
    <input type="radio" name="r" id="r2"><label for="r2" value="2">Search ony for</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Although he asked for JS, I do like this solution. +1

Answer (score 0):

You have to detect when the user checks the checkbox. Something like this will work:

```
document.getElementById('radio-id').onchange = function() {
    if(this.checked) {
        document.getElementsByClassName(cdiv1).style.backgroundColor = "green";
    } else {
        document.getElementsByClassName(cdiv2).style.backgroundColor = "green";
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this suggestion but in f12 I get the error message 'cannot set property onchange of null'

Comment: Did you change `radio-id` to your radio button's ID?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `change`

```
$('input[name="rbsearch"]').on('change',function(){
     if($(this)val()==1) {alert(1)}
    else{alert(2)
    }
    } )
```

Comment: I just tried a derivation of this suggestion and added ; semicolons but still getting syntax error in the if ... else section.  How to modify this to function correctly?  Many thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this which appears to do what I want

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input:radio[name=rbsearch]').change(function () {
        if (this.value == '1') {
            $(".cdiv1").css({background:"lime"});
            $(".cdiv2").css({ background: "orange" });
        }
        else if (this.value == '2') {
            $(".cdiv1").css({ background: "orange" });
            $(".cdiv2").css({ background: "lime" });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I got a working sample of my code here https://jsfiddle.net/richp/yc3w34y1/